# Handel Multiple Switch Buttons in XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a requirement (in XAMARIN) to capture 100s of toggle action from 100s switch box and remember. So that net time when I load the application it remembers the state of each Switch box. What I have created so far is a custom BindableProperty so I can use them repeatedly.
This is what I have done so far:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty LabelProperty =BindableProperty.Create("Label", typeof(string), typeof(CustomSwitchCell));
    public string Label
    {
       get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

And in XAML file

```
<Label Text="{Binding Label}" IsVisible="True"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"    />
    <Switch x:Name="SwitchName" IsToggled="{Binding ItemSwitch}"  Toggled="OnFavoriteClicked"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"   />
```

Now I use the Custom Cell in my main page like

```
<switch:CustomSwitchCell Label="Item1" />
<switch:CustomSwitchCell Label="Item2"/>
<switch:CustomSwitchCell Label="Item3"/>
<switch:CustomSwitchCell Label="Item4"/>
```

now it creates multiple Switch buttons with Lable mentioned , but I am not sure how to get the

> Toggled="OnFavoriteClicked" for each of them.
>   Is there any other Easy way to get multiple toggle actions and store it and load when the page loads without creating so many functions ?? 
>   Hope this clarifies ... please guide .. I am a new bee to XAMARIN..
>   Thanks,
>   MKJ

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a local db like sqllite. I use SQLite.Net.Core-PCL nuget most of the time.

```c#
public static class MyEnums
{
    On = 1,
    Off = 2,
    Unselected = 3
}
```

Some way to identify each toggle switch for future reference, I am assuming they have IDs.

```c#
public class Model_MySwitchWidget
{
    [Table("mySwitchWidget")]

    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    private int switchID;
    private int selectionStatus;    
    private int switchText;

    public static GetAll()
    {
        using(var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection())
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Model_Model_MySwitchWidget>(db.Table<Model_MySwitchWidget>().ToList());
        } 

    }

public static GetByID(int searchedSwitchID)
{
     using(var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection())
        {
            List<Model_MySwitchWidget> switches = 
            db.Query<ModelMySwitchWidget>("Select * FROM mySwitchWidget 
            Where switchID = ?", searchedSwitchID);
            return switches[0];
        } 
}

    public void InsertItem()
    {

         using (var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection())
            {
                db.Insert(this);
            }
    }

    public void UpdateItem()
    {
         using (var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection())
            {
                db.Update(this);
            }
    }
}
```

(Inside your switch)

```c#
private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
{
    if(oldvalue != newvalue)
    {
        var existingmodel = Model_MySwitchWidget.GetByID(this.switchID);
        if(exstingmodel == null)
        {
              var newswitch = new Model_MySwitchWidget();
              newswitch.selectionStatus = newvalue;
              newswitch.switchID = this.switchID;
              newswitch.switchText = this.switchText;
              newswitch.InsertItem();              

        }
        else
        {
             existingmodel.selectionStatus = newvalue;
             existingmodel.UpdateItem();
        }
    }
```

Now when you load your page, viewmodel or whatever just

```c#
var mycollectionofswitches = new ObservableCollection<Model_MySwitchWidget>(Model.MySwitchWidget.GetAll());
```

And you have a collection of saved switches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using the DB will result in so many columns (One per Item ) Correct ??

Comment: One *row per switch

Comment: Thanks , I am working on an approach where we can eliminate to store (status of the Toggle) in DB  as there might be 100s or more items in future.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would look like this:

**Requirements:** 
[James Montemango Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin)
You can also use a DB, but I think the settings plugin is implemented faster, its light weight and easy to maintain. It uses the native platforms tools to store persisting data on the device. And a nice JSon serializer, to serialize complex models into a string as the Settings Plugin can only store primitive types (int, bool, strings, etc.)
[NewtonSoft JSon Serializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Create a model class, that inherits from [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged/).
Each switch cell will have one model as it's binding context.

```
public class YourModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string labelText;
    private bool switchIsToggled;

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return labelText; }
        set 
        { 
            labelText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool SwitchIsToggled
    {
        get { return switchIsToggled; }
        set 
        { 
            switchIsToggled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

- Create a `ViewModel`
- Create an public Array, IList, or an ObservableCollection of `YourModel` in the `ViewModel`
- Set the binding context of your page to the `ViewModel`

Now there are two ways to go: you could easily create a ListView and then assign your collection of `YourModel` to the `ItemsSource` of the ListView.
When your `ViewModel` creates the collection, it can iterate through it and subscribe to each `SwitchIsToggled` bool:

```
foreach(YourModel switchModel in YourModelList)
{
    switchModel.PropertyChanged += Switch_PropertyChanged;
}

private void Switch_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if(sender is YourModel yourModel && args.PropertyName == SwitchIsToggled)
    {
        //code that should be called when switch was toggled
    }
}
```

If you dont want to have a scrollable list, then I would try this method on the Page:

```
public class YourPage : ContentPage
{

    public YourPage()
    {
        BindingContext = YourViewModel;
    }

    protected override OnBindingContextChanged
    {
        if(BindingContext is YourViewModel vm)
        {
            var stackLayout = new StackLayout();
            foreach(var yourModel in vm.YourModelList)
            {
                stackLayout.Children.Add(new CustomSwitchCell() { BindingContext = yourModel; }

                //or with event (not suggested, stick to MVVM!)
                //var newCustomSwitchCell = new CustomSwitchCell() { BindingContext = yourModel }
                //newCustomSwitchCell.Toggled += YourToggledEvent;
                //stackLayout.Children.Add(newCustomSwitchCell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And last but not least, everytime the app closes or whenever you want to: **Serialize the collection** from the viewmodel with the Newtonsoft JSon plugin into a string and **store it on the Settings class**, created by the settings plugin.

To restore the list just **deserialize** the previously serialized string from the settings class and **repeat the procedure** from start!

Looks like a lot, but it is easy to maintain, good luck!

Comment: Thanks , In the meantime , I have done a list of Custom cells where I have created a custom ViewCell with a Label and Switch Box ...

Comment: Wrongly my Ans was on top.But this is what I have done to get it done... Please see details on top for sample code.I have custom ViewCell and I can add the Custom ViewCell in Main page multiple time.
When I Toggle On the Switch, it save the Item Name to DB (not the toggle action).Next time when I load the application I check If the Name already exist on DB or not by iterating the Table Section for each of the Elements.If the Item Name Exists then the status of Switch is on , else Switch is Off..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the nice approach.
As explained above I have a Custom ViewCell.

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TODOListWithDB.Reusable.CustomSwitchCell">
<Grid BackgroundColor="Gold" Padding="13,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Text="{Binding Label}" IsVisible="True"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
    <Switch x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="SwitchName"   Toggled="OnFavoriteClicked"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"   />
</Grid>
```

And I can add the Custom ViewCell in Main page multiple time.

```
<TableSection Title="selectItems" x:Name="ParentTableSelection"><Switch:CustomSwithCell Label="item1"/><Switch:CustomSwithCell Label="Item2" />.....
```

When I Toggle On the Switch, it save the Item Name to DB (not the toggle action).Next time when I load the application I check If the Name already exist on DB or not by iterating the Table Section for each of the Elements.If the Item Name Exists then the status of Switch is on , else Switch is Off..  Not sure if that is the best way to do it . Thanks for nice different approaches ....

Comment: If u are really just showing this viewcell in the tableview only, then you should just use a listview + viewmodels for each viewcell and bind the listview to a list of the viewmodels. But if its works, its ok so far. Do more important stuff as you learn how to improve your approach